# Azure Policy - Deny New Network interfaces in vnets that doesn't have an specific tag

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-policy

I'm having a hard time to create a policy to deny the creation of network interfaces when the vnic is not connected to specific vnet\subnets (allowed vnets have a specific tag)

It looks like I can restrict the creation based on the network interface fields. In this case the only idea that came to my mind was to have a parameter configured with a list of allowed subnet ids, and deny based on this parameters. In this case I would need to build a separated mechanism to update this policy definition (Maybe a powershell script).

Just would like to ask if this is a good way to get it done and ask for suggestions,

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround ie built-in policy in azure “require an tag on resources” means under selected resource group when you create any resource without having any tag it will failed . Assign this policy in your resource group.

[image]

I have named tag ‘Rahul’ without Rahul Tag I won’t be able to create any resource under resource group

[image]

Here I repro and found without any specified tag I cannot able create any resources.

[image]

Comment: Make sure it might be deleted your previous resources which you have created without Specified tag under selected resource group

Comment: Thanks Rahul. The problem here is that I would like to deny the virtual interface creation, when the vnic is assigned to a not authorized subnet  (I have the tag in the vnet not in the vnics) .... I've created a policy with the subnet as a paremeter, and will use Set-AzPolicyAssignment to update the list of allowed subnets  in the policy assignment parameter

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it done using this:

```
"policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*]",
            "where": {
              "value": "[substring(current('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].subnet.id'),0,lastIndexOf(current('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].subnet.id'),'/'))]",
              "notIn": "[parameters('subnetId')]"
            }
          },
          "greater": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
```

And I'll pupulate the parameter with my vnets using the Set-AzPolicyAssignment to update the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a policy with the subnet as a paremeter, and will use Set-AzPolicyAssignment to update the list of allowed subnets in the policy assignment parameter – TheRob